Updating Firebase Analytics for Flutter to avoid privacy manifest policy issues (after May 1, 2024)
I recently received a notification on Firebase recommending an update to the Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) iOS SDK (version 10.24.0 or later) to avoid potential issues related to privacy manifest policies.
I'm developing a Flutter app and am unsure about the required package updates to ensure compatibility with the latest GA4F iOS SDK version.
Specific Questions:

Required Flutter Package: For a Flutter app targeting users after May 1, 2024, which Firebase package version is necessary to ensure compatibility with the updated GA4F iOS SDK (version 10.24.0 or later)?

Migration Steps: Are there any specific migration steps I need to follow when updating the Firebase package in my Flutter project?

Additional Considerations: Are there any other considerations or potential issues I should be aware of when updating Firebase Analytics for Flutter after May 1, 2024?

Open your Podfile (usually located in the project root).

Search for lines containing pod 'Firebase/Analytics'. You might see a version constraint like ~> 10.0.0. This indicates a minimum required version with some flexibility.
but didn't find anything like this.  I have good knowledge in flutter and android native but i am some short knowledge of iOS and i am looking for solution iOS provide some meaningful steps or information regarding it.



Apple introduced some rules regarding privacy. You are now required to have Privacy Manifest for every app uploaded to AppStoreConnect. Flutter documentation does not reflect this requirement yet but it is must-have. Since May 1st all apps without privacy manifest are denied. Here’s what you have to do:

Open your project in XCode. Be sure it is .xcworkspace
Click File > New > File...
Select App Privacy File and click Next
Be sure to select Runner and other targets if you have multiple
Click create and edit this manifest file

More details about Privacy Manifest is available under https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files
Firebase SDK should work if you haven’t updated it to latest version, however it is recommended to do so. Also Google stated that previous builts will not be affected, but only new ones will. You can upgrade your packages in pubspec.yaml and then update ios pods (it should happen automatically when you build, but from my experience it is best to update pods manually). To update navigate to ios folder and run pods update.
Also in iOS since I think ios 14 there is IDFA. In short it is responsible for displaying prompts to users if they allow for tracking. Firebase Analytics supports it but you can disable it in your Podfile. Add this line to do so:
$FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport = true

Then make sure to run pod install and check in your Podfile.lock if under PODS you have - Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport (10.25.0).
